# private operator delete in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, garbage-collection, new-operator

I'm working on a garbage-collection mechanism for a family of objects in one of my projects. What I want to have is allocate these objects dynamically with `new` and never having to call `delete`.

This is possible by overloading `operator new` to call into a specialized allocator object that implements GC for these objects (triggering collection when too much memory has been allocated). However, I have a problem: the user can still just do `delete` on these objects, and I don't want that.

Making `operator delete` private is problematic because of the way C++ handles failures in construction - if `operator new` is public, `operator delete` should be too. The alternative that's sometimes suggested is just make both `operator new` and `operator delete` private and only expose factory creation methods to the user. I can do this, but it feels less clean and requires extra code to write.

<strike>EDIT: Another approach is make `operator delete` empty (or throw an exception). Then, to actually release the objects my GC will call the destructor explicitly and then release the memory with the global `::operator delete`.</strike>

Any other ideas?

Comment: Just an idea: throw an error when someone tries to delete an object, that should teach them not to ;)

Comment: Offtopic: How do you track that object is out of scope? Why just not use shared pointer?

Comment: @Stormenet: I could do that although I wanted to use `delete` myself in the garbage collector (could've made it a `friend` if that operator were private).

Comment: @rmflow: I implement mark&sweep garbage collection, with tracing from known roots and all that

Comment: "make operator delete empty" - but then how is the memory freed when the constructor throws in a new expression? There's a *reason* it needs to be public, it's not just to make it look symmetrical ;-) [Edit - d'oh, I can answer that myself. Just make sure the GC can get it even if it hasn't been constructed. I think if you do this, though, you have to make sure you don't call the destructor twice in the case where the user `deletes` the object, the delete expression calls the destructor and then operator delete, which thows, and some time later you GC the object]

Comment: @Steve: can you rephrase (or write a more complete answer)? - I'm not sure I follow you.

Comment: There is a proposal [N2670](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2670.htm) for garbage-collection support for C++0x, however it does not discuss how delete is to be implemented. Perhaps the issue should be brought to attention of WG21 before C++11 is finalized.

Comment: @Eli: suppose you implement operator delete to do nothing, and the user writes the following code: `delete new GCedFoo();`. Then the delete expression will call the destructor before calling operator delete. However, you said that when the GC comes to release the memory, it will first call the destructor. So the destructor is called twice.

Comment: @Steve: you're right (as is @Jan Hudec in his comment to Benjamin's answer)... I'll erase the edit

Comment: @Eli: it might still be possible to hack your way around that. For example if your GC system keeps as meta-data whether the destructor has been called or not, and all GC objects must inherit from a base class whose own destructor sets that flag, then when you release the memory you can avoid destructing it again. I was just trying to say that there's more to it than simply "operator delete does nothing".

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think the idea of making both private and using the factory is the cleaner approach. Using new but not delete (or assigning to smart pointer) is going to confuse a lot of maintainers of the code.

If you can indicate that a pointer comes from a GC collected factory (or is owned by a GC collected factory) then it will make the code less confusing to maintain. By using a factory you are explicitly stating that the GC factory is the owner and thus should maintain the lifespan of the object:

```
class GCFactory
{
    public:
        template<T, P1>
        T& createGCObject(P1 const& p1) // Or return by pointer.
        {
            T* result = new T(p1);
            // Do stuff to register with garbage collector.

            // Then return object (I like reference) but I have not studied the
            // problem that hard so may be in-appropriate.
            return * result;
        }
        template<T, P1, P2>
        T& createGCObject(P1 const& p1, P2 const& p2)
        {
            T* result = new T(p1, p2);
            // Do stuff to register with garbage collector.

            return * result;
        }
        template<T, P1, P2, P3>
        T& createGCObject(P1 const& p1, P2 const& p2, P3 const& p3)
        {
            T* result = new T(p1, p2, p3);
            // Do stuff to register with garbage collector.

            return * result;
        }
};
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is when I have N different objects to allocate this way, each with its own constructor (one requiring two arguments, another a pointer and a reference, etc.) - this is a lot of code duplication (factory methods invoking corresponding constructors)

Comment: @Eli: With the right support for C++0x features, you may be able to solve that with perfect forwarding and variadic templates. See `vector::emplace_back`

Comment: @Steve: ah, C++0x, the promise that isn't... Unfortunately I'd really like it to run across several C++ compilers (MSVC included, sigh.) so this is probably not an option currently. Hopefully in the near future it will be!

Comment: @Eli Bendersky: You could get away with one method for n parameters by templatising all the parameters. Thus you only need one function for all constructors that take one parameter. One function for all constructors that take two parameters etc. Not a perfect solution but it will cut down on the code a lot.

Comment: @Eli: MSVC support for C++0x features might be better than you think - it's not like C99, MS is positive about C++0x, and plans more-or-less a full implementation. But sure, feature support isn't reliable across multiple implementations. You could also take a look at what Boost does, there are places it wants to use variadic templates and it does that where they're supported, and otherwise falls back to what Martin says in the comment above, which is to define n templates with 0 ... n-1 parameters. IIRC typical value for n is 10.

Answer (score 0):

Overload delete as a no-op. (more characters needed)

Comment: This leaves a problem: how does the GC actually delete these objects? I planned on using `delete`, alhtough I guess I can just call the destructor explicitly and then release the memory

Comment: I guess you're right - I added it in "EDIT", still looking for other ideas ;-)

Comment: Won't actually work. The compiler converts a `delete x` statement to `x->~Type(); Type::operator delete(x)`. I.e. the object *will* be destroyed first and than the memory won't be released by the no-op `operator delete`.

Answer (score -2):

```
boost::shared_ptr<Type> ptr = boost::make_shared<Type>();
```

You never call new, you never call delete.

Why reinvent the wheel?  Smart pointers really are the way to go.

Comment: +1; do this at the smart-pointer level, not the new/delete level.

Comment: Chris, I'm well aware of the existence of `shared_ptr`. This is not what my question is about, though

Comment: @Chris: reference counting != garbage collection.  For example, `shared_ptr` has real problems with cycles.

Comment: @Ben: 'shared_ptr has real problems with cycles' - could you elaborate please?   I wouldn't be trying to reinvent the wheel in 2011 I guess was my point.

Comment: @Chris: If two objects hold pointers to each other, `shared_ptr` will never free either one.  But mark-and-sweep garbage collection will free both (assuming no pointers from the outside world).

Comment: @Chris: if object C has a shared_ptr to object A, which holds a shared_ptr to B, which holds a shared_ptr to C, then none of them will ever be destroyed. I think that's what Ben meant about cycles.

Comment: @Chris: for this issue, "not re-inventing the wheel" is using Boehm's C++ garbage collector, which does mark-sweep. But Boehm's GC uses a lot of platform-dependent trickery to be as unobtrusive as possible - portable mark-sweep collection in C++ requires some help from the user, and that seems to be what Eli is going for.

Comment: I agree that shared_ptr was not the question, but the statement ``shared_ptr has real problems with cycles`` does not hold, because that's exactly what weak_ptr is here for.
A proper design with shared_ptr and weak_ptr is very predictable about object destruction and does not produce memory leaks.